# Incorrect number n of *args (Non-Keyword Arguments) at function in for cycle

Tags: python, tuples, arguments, keyword-argument, args

I'm a noob trying to complete some tasks and got a problem.
I have to calc arithmetic mean (I hope it's a correct definition) in function with *args (Non-Keyword Arguments).

So I have this

```
def avsum(*numbers):
summ = 0
print('Numbers', numbers)    
for n in numbers:
    summ += n
print('Calc', summ)
print('n', n)
print('Numbers', numbers)
result = summ / (n - 1)
return result


print(avsum(2, 3, 4))
```

All that prints are for just control and understanding what happens.
Terminal shows this:

```
Numbers (2, 3, 4)
Calc 9
n 4
Numbers (2, 3, 4)
3.0
```

As I was studied that *numbers are non-keyword arguments and they are tuple.
So in tuple numbers, I have 3 elements (Numbers (2, 3, 4)) but n is 4 for some reason.
I've made arithmetic mean like sum / (n - 1) but it looks like a weird solution.
Any ideas why is that happened? Why is n not 3?
Thanks for the reply.

**UPDATE**
Thanks for the reply, sorry maybe I'm stupid but I really can't understand how to make code in comments here 'readable'. As I got it right they are cannot be multi-line. This way I add it to question
So I had a close task:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    calc = 0
for n in array:
    calc += n
print("Sum", calc)
print("Arithmetic mean", calc / n)
print(n)
```

And terminal shows this

```
Sum 15
Arithmetic mean 3.0
5
```

So in this case there is no such error you are talking about, the array has 5 elements and n is 5. why? Here and there for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value n in the statement `for n in enumerate(numbers):` is a variable local to the for loop, it doesn't exist outside of the loop, therefore when attempting the statement `result = summ / (n - 1)`, you are most likely getting an error related to an undefined variable n.  To correct this error do:
`result = summ/len(numbers)`

Given that your input is now named array

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    calc = 0
for n in array:
    calc += n
print("Sum", calc)
print("Arithmetic mean", calc / len(array))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry maybe I'm stupid but I really can't understand how to make code in comments here 'readable'. As I got them are cannot be multi-line.
So I had a close task: 
'array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'
    calc = 0
for n in array:
    calc += n
print("Sum", calc)
print("Arithmetic mean", calc / n)
print(n)'

And terminal shows this
    Sum 15
Arithmetic mean 3.0
5

So in this case there is no such error you are talking about, array has 5 elements and n is 5. why? Here and there for loop

Comment: I added UPD to the question with all this code

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: thanks for the reply, I got that I should use `len` in 1st example with `def avsum` case, but in the second one with `array` it works well when I use even `calc / n` , that `n` number works correctly. So why does that happen when in one case `/ n` doesn't work but in the other case `n` - is the correct actual number of elements in `for loop`? It's kinda difference between arrays and tuples?

Comment: While I can't give yo a definitive answer, it seems the last value of n = 5 and it hasn't been over written, so it correctly computes.  Just because it works in this case, there is no guarantee, the value of n will always  be defined outside of the for loop, so it definitely is not a good practice.